# What is more efficient: Calling a method repeatedly or saving the result?

Tags: java, performance

What of the following is more efficient? Which solution is the better one (as the first one requires memory)? Does the compiler automatically save the result so that both solutions are the same? Note that the method getV() only returns the attribute value (which has private access).

```
void method(MyClass o) {
    int value = o.getV();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        // do something, but require value again
}
```

or

```
void method(MyClass o) {
    for (int i = 0; i < o.getV(); i++)
        // do something, but required o.getV() again
}
```

Comment: I want to say that it depends how the code is compiled, but generally, the constant value is extracted

Comment: @cricket_007 Which of course means the compiler needs to be sure that it's a side effect free call.